# How to structure vlookup calculations in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble , understanding how to go about structuring an excel model that is basically a bunch of top-down customer calculations, in python.

Excel calcs
excel model consists of many worksheets that look up a bunch of values and from different worksheets and perform calculations on a customer level.

each customer starts of  with an amount, a starting year ,an end year, and a starting state.

example of calculation in excel:
customer 1:
amount 100 , at starting state B , and starting year 3.

Multiplied by matrix (worksheet1)
the matrix consists of 10 3d arrays with states 5, (A-E).Each of the 10 3d arrays represent a year (1-10)

I multiply the amount 100 by the matrix at year and get an array, [800,650,400,300,840]

I then take this array and do another vlookup calculation, from another worksheet.
example limits (worksheet2). Which consists of years and limit %.

Year|Limit%

1. | 0.32
2. | 0.23
3. | 0.11
4. | 0.21

I vlook-up the customers year , year 3 in this case and then multiply [800,650,400,300,840] * 0.11

I then need to do a few more vlookup calculations like the one above.

after that

I need to multiply the result by the matrix at year 4, then do the vlookup calcs for year 4 like i did year 3, and basically continue until year 10 is reached.

Comment: So write the steps, which you have basically done. Then get the matrices and lookup data in a structure to use in Python, and then write the logic in Python code.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to understand what the data looks like form your description.  However, I would suggest creating `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.Series` of the constant data, with the identifier as the index value.  Then you can use `.loc()` to retrieve the relevant row and use this data.  If you returned this into your function until n = 10, you could calculate then return the final value.

A simple example that might help you start:

1. `matrix1` has columns as states ("A" and "B"), rows as years (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
2. `matrix2` has rows as year (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), and the data is the "limit%".

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# matrix1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5},
#                         'B': {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}})
matrix1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5, 5, 5).tolist(),
                       columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                       index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
matrix2 = pd.Series({1: 0.32, 2: 0.23, 3: 0.11, 4: 0.21, 5: 0.2})

def calculation(amount, year, starting_state, n, calcs={}):
    """
    This is the function that calculates everything. 
    :input amount: initial amount as int
    :input year: starting year as int
    :input starting_state: state in ["A", "B"] as str
    :input n: (end_year - starting_year) where end_year <= 5 and n > 0 as int
    :input calcs: dictionary of calculations, starting as empty as dictionary
    
    :return: final amount
    """
    
    #when there are no more years remaining
    if n == 0:
        #return amount
        return calcs
    
    #multiply by matrix1
    amount *= np.asarray(matrix1.loc[year, starting_state])
    #multiply by matrix2
    amount *= matrix2.loc[year]
    
    # more calculations ... 
    
    #add end result to dictionary
    calcs[year] = amount
    
    #return the new data to the function
    return calculation(amount, year+1, starting_state, n-1, calcs)
    

calculation(10, 2, "A", 5-2)
#Out: 1.27512
```

Running through the interations:

```
#10 * 2 = 20
#20 * 0.23 = 4.6
#return amount=4.6, year=3, "A", 3-1

#4.6 * 3 = 13.8
#13.8 * 0.11 = 1.518
#return amount=1.518, year=4, "A", 2-1

#1.518 * 4 = 6.072
#6.072 * 0.21 = 1.27512
#return amount=1.27512, year=5, "A", 1-1

#as n in now 0
#return 1.27512
```

If you have an initial dataframe with the input data, you can then append the end result to the data:

```
people = pd.DataFrame({"amount": [10, 11, 12, 13],
                       "starting_year": [2, 2, 1, 3],
                       "end_year": [5, 5, 4, 5],
                       "state": ["A", "A", "B", "A"]})

people["output"] = people.apply(lambda x: calculation(
    x["amount"], x["starting_year"],
    x["state"], x["end_year"] - x["starting_year"]), axis=1)

people
#Out: 
#   amount  starting_year  end_year state    output
#0      10              2         5     A  1.275120
#1      11              2         5     A  1.402632
#2      12              1         4     B  2.331648
#3      13              3         5     A  3.603600
```

## EDIT

The changes made to reflect your additions:

1. `matrix1` is now a 3-dimensional array to dataframe.  This has changed the creation of the dataframe (obviously), and the multiplication of `matrix1` needs to convert the returned `list` to an `np.array` so that it can be multiplied.
2. There is now an additional input to the function (which has a default of `{}` is no argument is passed, which is what you would want at the start.  Then in the last line of the function before the return I have added `calcs[year] = amount` which appends the year and the array for that year to the dictionary.  This means that the output of running for `people` is now a column of dictionaries.  If you want to expand this to columns for each year, you can add a line afterwards: `people = pd.concat([people, people["output"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)`.

Comment: I have made some changes to my answer.